# How to get the current address by google api in input type text

Tags: javascript, input, geolocation

I have got the current location with complete address and shown this in a `<span>` by ID. But i want to show this address in `input type text` also. My current code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var positionlatitude;
     var positionlongitude;
      var address;
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
       var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location_@item.Name'));
      google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
         var place = places.getPlace();
        address = place.formatted_address;
  positionlatitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    positionlongitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

               });
             });
                                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

        function success(position) {

        var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
  $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function (location) {
                                             $('span[id^="address"]').html(location.results[0].formatted_address); 
            })
              }
           </script>
     <label for="location">Your Location: </label><br />
      <span id="address" class="input-form" ></span>
   <input type="text" value="" name="address" id="geolocation"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To everyone If you consider this question.
 now i got the answer.

```
document.getElementById("geolocation").value = location.results[0].formatted_address;

 <input type="hidden" value="" name="address" id="geolocation"/>
```

This will set the address in `input type hidden`